# Way to partially filter inserted records in before trigger

Tags: dml, before-trigger

Let's say we have bulk DML that is gonna insert a couple of records. In before trigger we want to check all new records and insert only correct (matched) ones. Should we use another DML inside the trigger?

Comment: The only way to prevent the records from being inserted once they are in Trigger context would be to use addError on the records which you don't want to insert.

Comment: unfortunately addError stops execution after first `bad` record but there is need to insert rest `good` records

Comment: @pincet You need a partial insert (`allOrNone=false`), which can be set the DMLOptions header.